# Capture latest write to file/FIFO buffer and then flush the file/FIFO buffer

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe, buffer, fifo

Consider the following bash example:

```html
#!/bin/bash

ping -i 0.1 1.1.1.1 | while read ping_line
do
        echo $ping_line
        sleep 1
done
```

The processing on the right-hand side of the pipe is slower than the rate of the incoming pings on the left-hand side of the pipe. Here, the 'sleep 1' is intended to simulate a processing delay. And so the ping results that are output increasingly lag behind the incoming ping results.

So what if instead we want to always output **the latest available ping line**, and, only if necessary because processing is too slow, skip any intervening lines?

In particular, in bash how would you have ping write out to a file or fifo buffer, and then set up a while loop on that file or fifo buffer that echos **the latest available ping line** and flushes the file or fifo buffer after every read, ready for the next read of the **latest available ping line**?

So in terms of buffering, ideally the buffer is read from at the rate the values come in, but if there is any delay and the buffer grows to say [0 1 2 3], then we take '3' and discard '0', '1' and '2' for that read cycle. Because '3' is the **latest available ping line**.

Alternatively, if would also be acceptable to have ping blocked right after outputting one line, which line is then echoed, and then ping is unblocked, etc.

The idea is to keep a ping process going and each loop cycle work with the **latest available ping line** without a buffer or file size growing in perpetuity, hence the need to flush the file or fifo, or some other appropriate mechanism.

Here is my failed attempt:

```html
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/test
mkfifo $pipe

ping -i 0.1 1.1.1.1 > $pipe&
sleep 1

while read ping_line <$pipe
do
        echo $ping_line
        sleep 1
        dd if=$pipe iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null 2> /dev/null
done
```

I'd like it to echo the last write to the fifo buffer, then flush the fifo buffer, and repeat. So in this case it should output about every 10nth ping output line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `perl`'s sysread.  eg:

```
while sleep 1; do printf "$((i++)): "; date; done | 
while sleep 3; do
    perl -E 'sysread STDIN, my $s, 1024; @a=split /\n/, $s; say @a[-1] '
done
```

Note that this will *not* "flush" the fifo, but it will consume a good chunk.  You can tune the 1024, or add a while loop to consume everything.  (You can't flush an input stream, all you can do is read it to exhaustion.). Since you presumably don't care too much about losing data, you can consume the stream with something like:

```
perl -e 'my $r = sysread STDIN, my $s, 1024 while( $r == 1024 )'
```

(Just add that before the perl that actually prints anything)

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for this possible solution. Can you think of one that would not introduce a perl dependency? This is for use on a router.

Comment: `perl` is your friend.  Embrace it!  Honestly, without `perl` it's probably easiest to write something in C.  It's tough to get this kind of control with standard tools.  `bash`'s read builtin might be able to do it, but it's going to be insanely slow.

Comment: How does this compare to the bash approach I outline in a separate answer? I don't understand the mechanics very well.

Comment: I suspect the `head` solution is effectively the same as first `perl` (without the "flush" loop), except that it will be generally be writing older data.  (eg, on each read, it will print the first line instead of the last line).  But if the producer is generating enough data, the `head` will probably not read it all and the consumer will fall behind, as each `head` call will (probably) only consume some fixed amount (eg 4k or 8k or 16k, depending on the system config).

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a way to use: "dd if=$pipe iflag=nonblock of=/dev/null 2> /dev/null&" to flush in bash?

The real context I am agonizing over is this:

https://github.com/lynxthecat/sqm-autorate/blob/CAKE-autorate/monitor_reflector_path.sh#L71

'tail -f' in combination with truncation gives increased CPU with time for some systems. You may have a better idea for this context.

Comment: Also, in my example, doesn't the 'cat $pipe > /dev/null&' consume some data? I really appreciate your input because few seem to understand the relevant technical particulars here.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the `cat > /dev/null`.  That's quite ingenious.  Does it not work for you?  You have a race condition there and the `head` will almost certainly miss some data, but if that's acceptable that ought to work.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks a lot for your thoughts. Yes it seems to work. About the race condition, would there be any way to have the cat yield to head so that head takes priority? What will govern which gets priority? At the moment is seems 50/50 so head gets every second ping result. This is probably OK but would be even better if I could have cat let head go first. So that cat only consumes data if needed. Is some form of blocking in this situation possible? Or yielding?

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution, how about:

```html
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/test
mkfifo $pipe

ping -D -i 0.1 1.1.1.1 > $pipe&

cat $pipe > /dev/null&

while true
do
        head -1 $pipe
        sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This is fairly close, but the problem is that the head now competes with cat. What I really want is to replace this cat line with a background process that will ensure that $pipe only contains one line (so if $pipe ever grows beyond one line, to remove those excess lines).